# desktop напоминалка о днях рождениях с синхронизацией из xlsx

Tags: excel, desktop

Сначала задача.
Есть xlsx файл с датами рождения сотрудников. Нужна программа или скрипт которые будет парсить этот файл и показывать попап сообщение на рабочем столе о всех днях рождениях на следующие семь дней.

Почему все так плохо. Сотрудница котрой это надо, дама в возрасте и никаких гугл календарей или альтернативных решений она не признает. "Хочу запустить компьютер, и увидеть сообщение с днюхами".

Что я предлагал. Отдельную программу с возможностью импорта из csv. Макрос vba который показывает сообщение с будущими ДР в самом excel. Импорт файла с др в гугл календарь и синхронизацию его с календарем виндовс.

Ничего не подошло, потому что везде есть "лишние" телодвижения, такие как импорт или запуск экселя.
Возможно, кто-нибудь подскажет решение или даст совет куда двигаться.

Comment: *Excel* поставить в автозагрузку, разрешить работу макросов.  При первом запуске приложения (или при нескольких запусках) в этот день *VBA* сформирует список. Никаких лишних телодвижений.

Comment: 1. Простейшая служба на c#, которая подключает через VSTO Excel и считывает данные. Показывает окно WinForms либо при загрзуке. либо по расписанию 2. Еще проще - скрипт на python (или чем-то подобном), который включен на автозагрузку, при этом через pyopenxl или pandas считывает данные и выдает нужную информацию. При загрузке компьютера показывает окно tkinter  с нужной информацией.